# Define $Tf=f(0)$ Is $T$ continuous?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

> In $C[0,1]$ with the norm $||f||_1=\int_{0}^1 |f(t)|dt$ define
> $$Tf=f(0)$$
> Is $T$ continuous?

I try to use tools of calculus in fact something like the mean value theorem or maybe similar because I need explore the relation between $||T(f)||$ and $||f||_1$
Any hint or help I will very grateful

Comment: Can you imagine a continuous map having a high narrow hill at the origin with constant area equal to one?

Comment: Such as $f(x)=\begin{cases}\text{linear between }(0,2n)\text{ and }(\frac{1}{n},0)&x\le\frac{1}{n}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: One could also consider $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}$.

Comment: Consider the zero function say $\textbf 0$ so that $T(\textbf 0) = 0$. If $T$ was continuous then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there should exist a $\delta$ such that if $\|f\|_1 < \delta$ then $|f(0)| < \epsilon$. But this is not true since you can always have continuous functions which have larger values at $0$ but decrease rapidly away from $0$ so that the integral is bounded below $\delta$. There are such examples given by others here.